# Не удается получить доступ к api Яндекс

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

В статье указан способ, по которому можно получить доступ к API Яндекс: https://yandex.ru/dev/developer-help/doc/api/auth.html

Я получила ключ к API Поиска по организациям с тарифом Пробный. Запрос GET /projects возвращается с ошибкой 403.
Это происходит потому, что запросы к api недоступны с таким тарифом?

Ключ верный, запрос https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?text=<текст>&type=geo&lang=ru_RU&apikey=<полученный ключ> приходит со статусом 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API карт Яндекс находятся: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/quick-start/index.html

И там вся инструкция к получению ключа, до запросов.

https://yandex.ru/dev/developer-help/doc/api/auth.html - здесь находится API Кабинета разработчика - инструкция, и все данные от API

К каждому API - свой ключ, поэтому перейдите в https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/services/ - справа сверху будет кнопка "Подключить API", укажите интересующий Вас API, получите необходимый ключ, и следуйте дальнейшим инструкциям.